# Spring Integration Dynamic Inbound Channel

Tags: spring-integration

With Spring Integration, is it possible to dynamically create additional inbound channel adapters as the program runs?

Background:
I'm pretty new to SI and S-Batch. I'm using SI to poll our db for info that I use to create jobs in SB. Essentially, there are business rules for when the records I am pulling from the DB need to turn into a job. I'm planning on making an inbound channel adapter for each rule. For instance, the rule for items in their initial state would be:

`<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter 
        query="select [id] from [MY_DATA] where status_name = 'INITIAL'"
        ....
 />`

I plan on retrieving the rule info and parsing them into adapters. Instead of the hard coded rule above, I would retrieve the status_name "INITIAL" from the db and use that to build the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. You should instantiate `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` and set the `MessageSource<?>` for it and other important options, like `beanFactory` and `outputChannel`. After that you should `start()` the first one to begin polling.

But... Is that needed at all? Please, be more specific. What is the reason do that?

Maybe there is another solution with managed components?..

**UPDATE**

`SourcePollingChannelAdapter` is the main component to manage polling (scheduling) and MessageChannel. The hard task for producing messages is lie on the shoulders of `MessageSource<?>`. For your JDBC case there is `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`.

Yes, you should inject to your service `BeanFactory` and maybe `MessageChannel` for those dynamic adapters. I'm not sure that you will be able to populate your dynamic adapters back to the application context.

See this example for more info: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I've updated the Q with background info. Hope it helps!

Comment: Good. Ideally I need to sleep with that :-). But see if it wouldn't be better to have just only one poller for some `service method` which do all hard work with JDBC...

Comment: Would you mind expanding on your answer a bit? Is SourcePollingChannelAdapter what int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter creates behind the scenes? Would I just grab the context in the main app and inject my new adapter into it ala ConfigurableListableBeanFactory? Would this correctly attach it to the channels?